# Escape characters in Cassandra Select and condition

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I want to do a check a condition on Cassandra for a value like 'as(exprs)'.

```
Select 'as(exprs)' as test from temp where tempval = "'as(exprs)'"
```

I tried like,

```
''as(exprs)''
"'as(exprs)'"
"'"as(exprs)""
/'as(exprs)/'
//'as(exprs)//'
$$'as(exprs)'$$
```

But nothing worked. I'm running using Spark SQL, btw.

Comment: Please provide your schema

Comment: I'm checking the text value.

Comment: is as(exprs) a column name ?

Comment: No,'as(exprs)' is a String

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do this in Cassandra**

The only supported operation after SELECT are :

- DISTINCT
- COUNT (*)
- COUNT (1)
- column_name AS new_name
- WRITETIME (column_name)
- TTL (column_name)
- dateOf(), now(), minTimeuuid(), maxTimeuuid(), unixTimestampOf(), typeAsBlob() and blobAsType()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I could manage to do it with a concat operation in spark sql.